# Edge Animate set css on stage complete

Tags: javascript, animation, adobe-edge

Looking through the Edge Animate docs doesn't make it very clear when and how to apply extra scripts.

Not sure how to get something as simple as this to run after the stage is built, but before the animation is complete.

```
AdobeEdge.$('#Stage').css('background-color','transparent')
```

There are more complex things I want to run, but I need to get this to work first.